# groupby for pandas Series on a subset of hierarchical index not working

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Series indexed by a Hierarchical index that looks like this (result of some previous indexing and groupby):

```
myseries.index[0] = (('00037CLQ', '7/12/2013', 'AAA', 0L, 'BUY', 25L), 1000000.0)
myseries.index[1] = (('00037CMP', '7/8/2013', 'A', 0L, 'BUY', 25L), 1000000.0)
```

and so on

I would like to groupby on the subset of this index formed by the the last 6 entries, i.e. on `sub_index`, where

```
sub_index[0] = ('AAA', 0L, 'BUY', 25L, 1000000.0)
sub_index[1] = ('A', 0L, 'BUY', 25L, 1000000.0)
```

and so on

I tried a few things but none worked:

1. `myseries.reset_index(level=0)` drops the entire first tuple
2. flatten the nested tuples of the original index into a list of
       simple tuples and do myseries.reindex brings me to all `NaN`

Can somebody please shed some light?

Comment: a toy example to demonstrate this index would really help

Comment: Here is the toy example: 

index = [(('a',1,'AAA'),10), (('b',2,'AA'),20), (('c',3,'AAA'),20), (('d',4,'AA'),20), (('e',5,'AAA'),20), (('f',6,'AA'),10), (('g',7,'AAA'),10), (('h',8,'AA'),10)] 

myseries=Series(randn(8), index)

Group by only the last two entries of each nested tuple, i.e. group by 

sub_index = [('AAA',10), ('AA',20), ('AAA',20), ('AA',20), ('AAA',20), ('AA',10), ('AAA',10), ('AA',10)]

Comment: I also tried -please see toy example in previous comment- 

myseries.groupby( [(x[0][2], x[1]) for x in myseries.index] ).mean() 

But I got the following error message:
 
pandas.core.groupby.GroupByError: len(index) != len(labels)

Comment: Big MultiIndexes can be a hassle (to repeat some advice I dished out in another answer today). This one is particularly messy, with your nested tuple. It's difficult to imagine a situation where a tuples nested in a MultiIndex is a good idea. I suggest scrapping this approach and using columns. Any grouping you need should be more straightforward when you're working with named columns.

Comment: Dan, agree to a certain extent, but this particular messy multi-index came out of very natural operations: a df with a plain multiindex followed by a groupby on the multiindex itself and an additional column

Comment: @user2839122 Could you show these natural operations (with something toy e.g. df = pd.DataFrame(randn(5, 5), columns=list('abcde')) then do show us the groupby...

Comment: Andy, on your example "natural operations" would be for example 
 
df.set_index(['a','b','c'])

followed by 

mean_df = df.groupby([df.index, 'd'])['e'].mean()

now mean_df has exactly the index type (('a','b','c'),'d') I mentioned in the question and which is hard to manage